# How do you publish and subscribe to data that's not Mongo db?

Tags: reactjs, meteor

What's the process to have a Meteor.publish setup that performs some asynchronous request (e.g. an API) and then returns data which you want to display in a React component?  How does the publish work and how does the client side code access this?  I want to do this with the withTracker function if possible.  Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have a file here: ./imports/api/campaigns.js where I do `if (Meteor.isServer) {
  // This code only runs on the server
  // Only publish tasks that are public or belong to the current user
  Meteor.publish('campaigns', function campaignsPublication() {
    const self = this;
    const campaigns = factory.methods.getDeployedCampaigns().call();

    campaigns.forEach(campaign => self.added('campaigns', campaign, campaign));
    self.ready();
  });
}`  then in ./imports/ui/pages/index.js where I try to `export default withTracker(() ... const handle = Meteor.subscribe('campaigns');`

Comment: @ArmanS can you show us how you publish your data? If you publish it correctly, client side should be able just to do something like `<YourCollection>.find()` and then get the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This guide should help: [Publications and Data Loading](https://guide.meteor.com/data-loading.html).

Basically, you need to understand how Meteor's [low-level API](https://guide.meteor.com/data-loading.html#custom-publication) works so that you know how to publish any data set you want to a client-side Mongo collection. Also, to publish data from other API endpoints, [this part](https://guide.meteor.com/data-loading.html#loading-from-rest) of the guide shows a pretty clear example.

As for subscribing this kind of customized publication on the client side, it's just as simple as how you subscribe from typical MongoDB type publication. Note that the difference is, as I mentioned above, you are publishing to/subscribing from a [Client-side collection](https://guide.meteor.com/collections.html#client-collections).

Below is a simple example I wrote by myself. I don't really know about React, but the client code is mostly based on Meteor's tutorials:

- [Collections](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/collections)
- [Publish and subscribe](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/publish-and-subscribe)

---

```js
/* client side */
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withTracker } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor'; 
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';

const Foo = new Mongo.Collection('Foo');

class App extends Component {
  renderFoo() {
    return this.props.foos.map((foo) => (
      <Foo key={foo._id} foo={foo} />
    ));
  }
}

export default withTracker(() => {
  Meteor.subscribe('publishFromAnApi', ...args);
  return {
    foos: Foo.find().fetch(),
  };
})(App);


/* server side */
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { HTTP } from 'meteor/http';

Meteor.publish('publishFromAnApi', function publishFromAnApi(...args) {  // must use a function instead of an arrow function here for the sake of `this`
  const publishedKey = {};
  const collectionName = 'Foo'; // same name of the client side collection mentioned in line 6

  const poll = () => {
    const { data } = HTTP.get('/some/api/route', { ...someArgsToRequest });
    for (let i = 0; i < data.responseFromAPI; i += 1) { // just a random example here, assuming responseFromAPI is an array
      const document = data.responseFromAPI[i];
      const id = <the id of the document; normally is in Mongo.ObjectID type>;

      // some logics might be going on...

      if (!publishedKey[id]) {
        this.added(collectionName, id, document);
        publishedKey[id] = true;
      } else {
        this.changed(collectionName, id, document);
      }
    }
  };

  poll();
  this.ready();

  const interval = Meteor.setInterval(poll, <poll interval>);

  this.onStop(() => {
    Meteor.clearInterval(interval);
  });
});
```

[meteor](/questions/tagged/meteor)

Comment: Thanks Fliss Hou, I had been staring at those pages for several days and trying to figure it out and still can't.  I think I have the publish part right (possibly).  But there is no example of the React component side anywhere and how you use the withTracker function to access the data in the React component.

Comment: I found [this tutorial](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/collections) mentioned `withTracker()`.